# Do Lucky Eggs Hatch?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I was wondering if lucky eggs hatched in Pokemon ORAS because I caught a Pelliper with one and was reading that they boosted exp. Do they only boost exp, or do they hatch, too? Thx

Answer (score 6):

Lucky Eggs are items, not Pokémon eggs. They don't hatch.